# Bindings and Core Data: the entity xxx is not key value coding-compliant for the key "(null)"

Tags: macos, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I've build up a a little application to get my head around macOS programming. I've several table-views with some having a `NSPopUpButtonCell`.

Those `NSPopUpButtonCells` cause randomly a crash

```
2016-07-05 14:45:10.331 TrainingplanMac[94732:35004946] [<TrainingplanMac.Workout 0x6180000a6de0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Workout is not key value coding-compliant for the key "(null)".
2016-07-05 14:45:10.334 TrainingplanMac[94732:35004946] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffa050b4f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9a51973c objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffa050b439 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   CoreData                            0x00007fff9ebddd91 -[NSManagedObject valueForUndefinedKey:] + 289
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff98d14ed5 -[_NSPopUpButtonPlugin showValue:inObject:] + 734
```

The error occurs randomly if I've touched the storyboard. If I do not touch the storyboard I'm able to rebuild the project as often as I like without the error appearing. If the error appears I fiddle with some settings in the storyboard and after a few rebuilds it's gone. Also it's not every time the same entity which causes the error. Each `NSPopupButtonCell` has an other entity which it display and the error occurs randomly for every button/entity.

It's rather frustrating because every time I want to try something new I have to build/run/fiddle/build/run/fiddle... until the application will run.

Don't know what other information might be helpful. Due to not having enough reputation I'm not able to embed the pictures. Sorry for that.

**[Edit]**

I've reproduced the problem from scratch in a small project. I've made the project available here: [Project removed because it's not longer needed]. I think I've done everything according to Apple's Binding Guide, but ... :)

Removed Links to pictures because of "Only 2 links limit".

Comment: Your cell bindings image appears to be the same as the table bindings image.

Comment: They aren't. It's quite misleading - I had to check it twice to be sure :)  I think it would be clearer if I would be able to embed them - sorry for that.

Comment: Ah yes.  I think you may have to clarify what you mean by "cell" then.  Not table cell binding through objectValue, but the popup bindings within the cell?

Comment: Clarified that. At least I hope I did :)

Comment: Is the table view view based or cell based?

Comment: The table view is cell based.

Comment: If anyone finds any wrong doing in the provided project which does not affect the problem I would appreciate hints on that too.

Comment: If the table view is cell based, you don't have to bind content, selection indexes and sort descriptors.

Comment: @Willeke I removed them and now everything works as a charm. Thank you very much. I don't know where I picked up those bindings. Probably I've mixed up to many tutorials ;)

Comment: @stevesliva good idea :)

Comment: @Willeke I got it from Apple's documentation: 

_Also, because you bind a view to a controller, you need to be familiar with the properties of controllers. These are the primary properties of an array controller that you typically use as the value of the Controller Key aspect:

arrangedObjects—specifies the collection of objects being displayed.
selection—specifies the selected object in arrangedObjects.
selectedObjects—specifies ..._

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Tasks/masterdetail.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002090-BCICADHC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table view is cell based, you don't have to bind content, selection indexes and sort descriptors.

From the documentation of NSTableView Bindings:

> Typically, the content binding is created automatically when the initial NSTableColumn binding is made, binding to the column's NSArrayController.